# Text of textbox doesn’t update in submit button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two radiobutton. If one of them be checked a textbox be active and get data.
They are in update page. In page-load fill them by data from database and I check ispostback.
If textbox have text in page load, its text change and everything work fine but if it haven’t text in first place, it keep default text and doesn’t update in submit button click.

```
    String val = "0";
    if (radiobutton2.Checked && textbox1.Text.Length != 0)
            val = textbox1.Text;
```

in page load use this code for initialize radiobuttons:

```
    t.ReadOnly = true;
    t.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
```

and there's a javascript code for active and inactive this textbox

```
    function CheckedChanged(rbtnelement, txtelement) {
                    if (document.getElementById(rbtnelement).checked) {
                        document.getElementById(txtelement).readOnly = false;
                        document.getElementById(txtelement).style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById(txtelement).readOnly = true;
                        document.getElementById(txtelement).style.backgroundColor = "grey";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: if (radiobutton2.Checked)
        if (textbox1.Text.Length != 0)
            val = textbox1.Text; what did u mean by this ?

Comment: I can't get u ? actually what do u want to achieve ? if your textbox1 have no text then you want to save a default value ? is it like that?

Comment: there is larger code and i cut most of it but i want save textbox's text if it have any text and radiobutton2 is checked. i edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because the textbox readonly property become false in c# code (it run in server side) and it become true in javascript (it run in client side). In server side (c# codes) textbox remain readonly and don’t send its text.

if remove one of them and manage textbox in one side (client or server) it will work fine.